# Facebook Graph api Event crawling

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am developing something like an event calendar at the moment and would like to pimp it up with a bit more "live" data. Therefore I want to get data from Facebook and I think the right way to do this is the Graph api.

But I really cant get it working. I would like to either:

1. get all Events in a specific range from a Location (I don't think this is possible)
2. or get all Events from a specific page
3. or get all Data from a specific Event

But I don't get the API Documentation. 
Do I need a Page API-Key or an Api API-Key. I don't even get the the Graph API Explorer to output any data. 
When I want to crawl a Page I get 
"(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.","

I know it sounds quite obvious but I just want to test a bit and get to know the api before I develop the app. I can't submit anything right now..

Comment: you need to test with a page you manage

Comment: Okay thanks!
And do you know what they exactly review in the review process?
And after the review, I can also use public pages ?

Comment: they review your usage of their api, of course.